# Scan barcodes consecutively with zxing

Tags: java, android, zxing

I'm currently using ZXing to scan barcodes in my app.
I can scan a barcode, save the result and open the scanner again to scan multiple barcodes, but I want the scanner to remain open so I can scan multiple products one after each other.

I followed this (https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) Tutorial so far, but it does not provide information on how to scan them with keeping the scanner on screen.

On iOS it is possible with the ZBar SDK.

Thanks for your input and help.

Comment: If someone looking for solution https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. You can do it with the app itself but not by Intent.

Comment: Is there any documentation available for this approche?

Comment: @Sean Owen could you please suggest a way to implement/achieve this. It will be very much helpful for me as it is very immediate requirement for me. thanks!